# Turn one row into multiple rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple items that are available in multiple distribution centers (i.e., a many-to-many relationship). There is currently one row per item, with one column for each distribution center. A cell in the row for item *X* and the column for distribution center *Y* is marked with the code for distribution center *Y* if item *X* is available there and blank otherwise. An item with multiple distribution centers will have multiple distribution center codes (in their respective columns). So the current sheet looks like:

```
    |   A    |         B         |*|                      S-AJ                      |
1   |  ID #  |   Description     |…|              Distribution Centers              |
2   |   17   |   Ginkgo Biloba   |…|      |      |      |      |      |      |  SE  |
3   |   42   |   Ginseng         |…|      |  MP  |  MS  |      |  NW  |      |      |
                     ︙
```

Columns `C` through `R` contain other attributes of the items, such as UPC code, cost, and price, which are not relevant to this question. My actual sheet has 18 distribution centers, spanning columns `S` through `AJ`; I reduced that to get the example to fit into Stack Exchange’s window.

I need to have a single distribution center column, with a single distribution code per row, and then duplicate the rows as needed for items that currently contain multiple codes. The result should look like:

```
    |   A    |         B         |*|   S  |
1   |  ID #  |   Description     |…|  DC  |
2   |   17   |   Ginkgo Biloba   |…|  SE  |
3   |   42   |   Ginseng         |…|  MP  |
4   |   42   |   Ginseng         |…|  MS  |
5   |   42   |   Ginseng         |…|  NW  |
                     ︙
```

where cells `A3:R3`, `A4:R4`, and `A5:R5`, contain the same information.

The only way I can think of doing this, which would be time consuming, would be to copy the item number into multiple rows; and in the column that has the distribution code I would change code for the item that is available in each distribution center. I will be doing this for 900 items. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Could you please add the sample?

Comment: Yes, a sample of what the data looks like, and what you've attempted that isn't working.

Comment: In case this isn't obvious, we need an example of the data layout you have now ***and*** what you want to end up with.

Comment: Below is an small sample of what I want to do. I will be doing this for 900 items.   
Current sheet
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FU0KS.jpg
What I want to do.
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/s7uQP.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split one row into multiple rows with Excel?](http://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel)

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new sheet. 
   Copy the header row(s), the column widths, and the formats,
   except do not copy Columns `T`-`AJ`. 
   It may be easiest to copy the entire sheet,
   then delete all rows other than 1 and unmerge Columns `S`-`AJ`.
2. First we want to replicate each item row from `Sheet1` onto `Sheet2`
   18 times — once for each distribution center. 
   Type `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, INT((ROW()-2)/18)+2, 1) & ""` in `Sheet2!A2`. 
   `INT((ROW()-2)/18)+2` maps rows 2-19 on `Sheet2` to row 2 on `Sheet1`,
   rows 20-37 on `Sheet2` to row 3 on `Sheet1`, etc. 
   The `& ""` causes Excel to display a blank
   when referencing a blank cell in `Sheet1`. 
   If you don’t have any blanks in `Sheet1`, you can leave this off. 
   If you don’t like this particular solution,
   you can use one of the other solutions from
   [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/515932/150988).

   Drag/fill this to the right, to cell `R2`.
3. Enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!$S:$AJ, INT((ROW()-2)/18)+2, MOD(ROW()-2, 18)+1)`
   into `Sheet2!S2`. 
   This references the same row in `Sheet1` as the above formula,
   but `Sheet2!S2` gets the value from `Sheet1!S2`,
   `Sheet2!S3` gets the value from `Sheet1!T2`,
   `Sheet2!S4` gets the value from `Sheet1!U2`, etc.
   This will display `0`s for blanks.
4. Select the entire row `A2:S2` and drag/fill down to get all your data. 
   This will need to be 18 times as many rows as you have on `Sheet1`;
   i.e., 18×900=16200.
5. Copy all of `Sheet2` and paste values.
6. Filter Column `S`. 
   Display only the zeroes. 
   Delete all the rows (other than row 1). 
   Remove the filter.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Easier solve but more manual effort:
Copy the unique ids x no of time (where x is no of columns to be converted to rows) for each iteration apply vlookup with the column to be converted to rows each time