# How do I conditionally format a cell based on time?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to conditionally format a cell based on time.

- Two hours prior to a time I want the cell to turn green.
- 1 hour before the time I want it to change to orange.
- 30 minutes before it should turn red.

How would I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
=B1<(NOW()-today())
```

Comment: Just some friendly advice, you may want to edit the title of your question to reflect the specific question you have, which I assume is regarding excel. Something like "MS Excel conditional formatting based on time" would be more informative to question answerers and future readers that have similar questions.
As for your actual question, it would be very helpful to put in a bit of a chart such as [here](http://superuser.com/questions/889201/turn-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-excel). Use four spaces to begin the segment that displays your sample data.

Comment: The cell will only update - and therefore reformat - if you do something.  I assume you have tried running a macro that recalculates at intervals.

Comment: @inkyvoyd I already fixed it ;)

Comment: DavidPostill thanks.
@Steve G, do you necessarily wish to refer to a current time, or are you more concerned with times listed on a spreadsheet?

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/#based-current-date

Comment: Updated my answer - had it backwards in my rush.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional format rules will need to be like this -

```
=IF((F1-(NOW()-TODAY()))*1440<0,TRUE)
=IF((F1-(NOW()-TODAY()))*1440<30,TRUE)
=IF((F1-(NOW()-TODAY()))*1440<60,TRUE)
=IF((F1-(NOW()-TODAY()))*1440<120,TRUE)
```

But you'll need four rules, with the smaller ones stopping when true. Put them in the above order, but use whatever cell your times start in instead of `F1`

You should apply this to only the first cell then right click and drag down and hit "fill formatting only" - otherwise it will use the `F1` in every case rather than each cell.

[image]

[image]

[click for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaG16.png)
[image]