# Excel: Expand list to include duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to dynamically expand a list to include duplicates. I managed to achieve this without VBA, but after condensing several columns containing intermediary functions I have tied myself in a knot of circular references. I'm not convinced I can get it working again, so I turn to SU for help.

I have a table as below:

```
        APPLE  BANANA   CHERRY  DATES
JOHN      x                x
PAUL              x
GEORGE    x       x
RINGO     x       x        x      x
```

I need to create from this two columns containing the following:

```
JOHN         APPLE
JOHN         CHERRY
PAUL         BANANA
GEORGE       APPLE
GEORGE       BANANA
RINGO        APPLE
RINGO        BANANA
RINGO        CHERRY
RINGO        DATES
```

That is, each individual instance of Fruit is listed.
I am able to create the second column, i.e. the list of fruits according to the Eater; I just can't get the first column.

From here the list will be expanded again. Let's say I have another table:

```
FRUIT    LINES
APPLE      2
BANANA     3
CHERRY     1
DATES      2
```

The ultimate list I would like to end up with is:

```
JOHN         APPLE          1
JOHN         APPLE          2
JOHN         CHERRY         1
PAUL         BANANA         1
PAUL         BANANA         2
PAUL         BANANA         3
GEORGE       APPLE          1
GEORGE       APPLE          2
GEORGE       BANANA         1
GEORGE       BANANA         2
GEORGE       BANANA         3
RINGO        APPLE          1
RINGO        APPLE          2
RINGO        BANANA         1
RINGO        BANANA         2
RINGO        BANANA         3
RINGO        CHERRY         1
RINGO        DATES          1
RINGO        DATES          2
```

That is, each line is repeated according to the number in the "Fruit/Lines" table. I'm sure this second step is just a replication of the first step, rather than one complete set of functions.

Any help will be appreciated.

The duplicate question, [Turn one row into multiple rows in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/889201/turn-one-row-into-multiple-rows-in-excel), doesn't cover the dynamic element; steps 5 and 6 are "copy list and paste values" and "filter column and delete nulls" are not suitable for this application.