# Merge columns into single one based on ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, how can I merge multiple columns into single one
(i.e., split one row into multiple rows) based on ID?

The image below illustrates what I want to do.
`ID` and `Catalog Code` are unique but their assigned `Supplier` and `Supplier Code` aren't (e.g., cells `F6` and `H4`).

This is just a sample of my data (the full data set has over 15000 rows).

[image: THIS IMAGE EXPLAINS EVERYTHING]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split one row into multiple rows with Excel?](http://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbScript to automate this activity

### High Level Logic

1. Create a file named excel.vbs
2. [Open existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312566/open-update-and-save-excel-workbook-automatically)
3. Create a new sheet in the same file
   Set objWrkBk = objXL.Workbooks.Add
4. Create a iteration block using for, while or your preferred code to read the data from this existing file
5. within the loop start writing data to your logic. you would be able to increment the columns  numbers in each pass
6. Save the new file