# Libreoffice: create multiple rows from 1, depending on row content

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a style sheet in Libreoffice, like this:

```
       DateA | DateB | DateC | DateD
---------------------------------------
John |     1 |     1 |     0 |     1
Mary |     0 |     1 |     0 |     1
```

What I want is to create a new style sheet, like this

```
     | Date
---------------------------------------
John | DateA
John | DateB
John | DateD
Mary | DateB
Mary | DateD
```

In other words: create a row per person **and per date**. The result would be multiple rows per person, whereas in the original file each person has one row with multiple dates.

There are similar questions about Excel ([like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel)), but unfortunately I only have Libreoffice. Any help is appreciated.