# copy formalas of multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have worksheet with 100 rows (for example). I creating a new sheet to cover it to 400 rows. 
The original looks like:

```
name1, value1, name2, value2 
a, 1, b, 1
c, 1, d, 1
```

Want to make the new sheet looks like:

```
name, value, joined
a, 1, ab
b, 1, ab
c, 1, cd
d, 1, cd
```

The formal I'm using in the first two rows are:

```
=sheet1!A2, =sheet1!B2, =CONCATENATE(sheet1!A2,sheet1!C2)
=sheet1!C2, =sheet1!D2, =CONCATENATE(sheet1!A2,sheet1!C2)
```

Now I want to copy those formulas to all the other rows, but if I select those and drag it will only pay attention to the formula in the last row.
I tried also with VBA but the debugger is worthless(saying there is an error without pointing to the line/actual error).

**Edit**
When I mark all of the rows and drag with ALT pressed it preserved the formulas but it add `+2` to the rows instead of `+1`. Getting closer..

**Edit 2**

Sort in VBA by putting break points on each line to identify the problematic line.
[Link to the VBA example I took](https://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel) - doing pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest an array formula free solution using `IF, MOD, ROW, OFFSET, ROUNDDOWN` functions along with the `CONCATENATE` you have been using.

This is possible by mapping each consecutive two rows in Sheet 2 to one in Sheet1.

```
Rows 2,3 in Sheet2  -> Row 2 in Sheet1 (i = 0)
Rows 4,5 in Sheet2  -> Row 3 in Sheet1 (i = 1)
...
```

Let's say 5th row in Sheet1 (using A5)

```
ROUNDDOWN((row(A5)-row(A$2))/2,0)
```

is equal to `1`. (`i=1`)

You also need to know whether a row in Sheet1 is the first one or the second one. This means determining a row is even or odd if we start counting from row 2. (i.e. row 2 -> 1(odd), row 3 -> 2 (even), ... ) This is achieved by using `MOD` as such,

```
mod(row(A5)-row(A$2),2)
```

This returns `1` since (`5-2=3` is an odd number.)

The rest is combining these in `IF`s for the first two columns and `CONCATENATE` for the third with `OFFSET` to reach the contents in Sheet 1. Formulas for each of the three columns are displayed below the table. Values you have given are changed to `1,2,3,4` (row major numbered sequence) in order to check whether correct cells are captured or not.

[image: multiple rows]