# Pivot table - Summarising multiple independent data columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table containing daily inputs into a system, which has the columns as shown:

Day Itemname1 Itemquant1 Itemname2 Itemquant2 .....

The item names and quantities are independent of each other. On one day, one might receive 10 Item A, and on another day, one might receive 5 of Item D, 6 of Item B, and 234 of Item C. In the former case, only 2 colums will have data, and in the latter case, 6 columns will have data. All the other columns will be empty. An example:

```
Day N1  Q1  N2  Q2  N3  Q3
1   A   10
2   D   5   B   6   C   234
```

How would a pivot table be used to display, say, the quantities of A daily over a year, or the number of non-zero values of A in a year? Note that A may appear in multiple columns, and there are hundreds of possible items, so simply creating a table with each variable in a column is not feasible.

I have tried adding all of the columns in multiple ways, but it ends up returning the values of A, given all the values of B, given all the values of C, which is useful if the values are dependent, but clutters up the page since they are uncorrelated.

If this is not possible, what would be a good method to obtain the information required from the spreadsheet?

Comment: If the explanation is unclear, the problem is very similar to http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/351138-pivot-tables-multiple-columns-same-data.html or http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/529518-pivot-tables-combine-multiple-columns-original-data.html

Comment: Ok.. What i understand from Mr.Excel question of yours is that, when a truck comes in for services a record (in the table) is created. And more than one part is serviced. please see my sample (in answer) table for one month showing the details. Is this the format you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You desperately need to reorganize your data. It's a really bad idea to have an indeterminate number of columns for reasons you're running into now. My advice is, as others have suggested, to convert your data to a simple three-column table with a row for each daily item.

```
Day  Item  Quant
 1     A     10
 2     D      5
 2     B      6
 2     C    234
```

Then you can use a pivot table to summarize and drill down into the data as you wish.

So, now the issue is how to go about reorganizing this data in an indeterminate number of columns. Luckily, a fairly simple VBA procedure can do this. Paste the code below into a new VBA module (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, then go to `Insert` > `Module`).

```vb
Sub SalvageMyTable()
Dim sOrig As Worksheet, sOut As Worksheet
Dim arrIn() As Variant
Dim rOut As Range, arrOut() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set sOrig = ActiveSheet
'Store original data in an array for faster processing
arrIn = sOrig.UsedRange.Value
'Create maximal output array. This can be resized before outputting the data.
ReDim arrOut(0 To 2, 0 To UBound(arrIn, 1) * (UBound(arrIn, 2) - 1) / 2) As Variant
'Loop through original table and copy values to output array.
For i = LBound(arrIn, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrIn, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrIn, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrIn, 2) Step 2
        If arrIn(i, j) <> "" Then
            arrOut(0, k) = arrIn(i, LBound(arrIn, 2))
            arrOut(1, k) = arrIn(i, j)
            arrOut(2, k) = arrIn(i, j + 1)
            k = k + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'Resize output array
ReDim Preserve arrOut(0 To 2, 0 To k) As Variant
'Create output sheet and print output there.
Set sOut = Worksheets.Add
sOut.Name = "Reorganized Data"
sOut.Range("A1").Value = "Day"
sOut.Range("B1").Value = "Item"
sOut.Range("C1").Value = "Quantity"
sOut.Range("A2").Resize(k, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrOut)
'Reset Excel settings
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Be sure to have the worksheet with your original data open. Then go to the VBA editor and run this code (by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>). This code will output the transformed data in three columns on a new worksheet named "Reorganized Data".

Answer (score 1):

In order to ever be able to reliably complete data analysis on that data set, you need to change how the data is setup/organized/entered.

It can be done in Excel, but it would be a pretty easy database to setup as well.

Table for Items (item num, name, desc)
Table for Vehicles (vehicle num, name, desc, type, make model)
Table for Usage (item num, vehicle num, date, number used)

You could also do this in Excel with different sheets and using data validation to give them a drop down of the item and vehicle in the usage sheet.  If you don't have programming experience that might be the best option.

Sorry to not answer your problem, but the real problem is the organization of your data.

Comment: Would you then be able to provide an alternative organisation which works better than this current one, considering the constraints of the system?

Comment: First I am not sure what your constraints are.  That was not in the questions.  Second, I would try @Excellll answer of reorganizing it and see if that gives you an ideas.  Third, the structure is in the answer.  A list of vehicles, a list of items to use on the vehicle, and a list of when items are used.

Comment: "Note that A may appear in multiple columns, and there are hundreds of possible items, so simply creating a table with each variable in a column is not feasible. "

Comment: It is not "not feasible".  It's work.

Answer (score 0):

You will first convert the table in below format
Day N Q with sample data as

```
1 A 10
2 D 6
2 B 6
2 C 234
```

Then if you pivot on this table, you should get the result.
To convert into above table, you create a new sheet. Suppose you have 10 rows and 3name quantity pair in main sheet (Assuming Sheet1 as the name of the sheet and not header row/column) then you can use below formula in new sheet from row 1 to 30 (10*3)

```
1    =Sheet1!A1  =Sheet1!B1  =Sheet1!C1
    ...
10   =Sheet1!A10  =Sheet1!B10  =Sheet1!C10
11   =Sheet1!A1  =Sheet1!D1  =Sheet1!E1
    ...
20   =Sheet1!A10  =Sheet1!D10  =Sheet1!E10
21   =Sheet1!A1  =Sheet1!F1  =Sheet1!G1
    ...
30   =Sheet1!A10  =Sheet1!F10  =Sheet1!G10
```

Comment: If this was the case, it would be trivial to do the conversion, but the number of entries per day varies and is not always 3. This would result in a large number of blank spaces (as there can be anywhere from 0 to 20 different items per day, but the average is 2), not to mention being extremely unelegant.

Comment: You have the right idea, even if the method for reorganizing the data isn't perfect. Get the data into three columns and then let the pivot table work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In. It takes a few steps to get there but no code or changes to your input data structure are required.

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Summarising multiple independent columns" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically my technique was to build 2 preliminary Queries, one to unpivot the "N" values and one to unpivot the Q values (converting multiple columns into multiple rows), then a final query to Merge the two datasets back together.

At that point you have a normalised table which is ideal for exploration by filtering or using a Pivot Table and/or Pivot Chart.

Answer (score -1):

Please find this image below. The ones represent the part that was serviced and zero represents the part that was "not changed". If this is how your data is represented then you can use simple pivot table to solve your problem.
[image]

Comment: This is not how the data is presented, as seen above. It would also be unpracticeable to convert the data, for reasons shown above.

Comment: Can you present an excel sample as above?

Comment: I'd be very much interested to see the organization of your data. As @Kingofalltrades says, it is the format of your data that is causing the issue. For some reason, I think, what is shown above is the most effective way of representing your data. It gives you flexibility. The same truck can come more than once per day - can have multiple things fixed per day etc., It is more of a "restaurant menu chart" in my perspective.. I could be wrong too...