# Power Query - How can I convert these columns into rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I feel like I've done this before but the correct process is eluding me. For the data below, where the location and qty columns repeat at least 15 times:

```
Item    Location    Qty    Location    Qty    Location   Qty....
AAAA    A           2      B           3      D          10
BBBB    C           5      D           20
```

How can I get it into the format below?

```
Item    Location    Qty
AAAA    A           2
AAAA    B           3
AAAA    D           10
BBBB    C           5
BBBB    D           20
```

For this example, there are thousands of items, so I can't do any sort of manual grouping per-item.

Edit:

Going the unpivot route gets me this, and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
AAAA    Location      A
AAAA    Qty           2
AAAA    Location_2    B
AAAA    Qty_2         3
```

Comment: google for "unpivot", it'll give you plenty of hints

Comment: Exactly how many location columns do you have ??

Comment: Maybe not what you're looking for, but here's a programming answer for a similar question on StackOverflow: [Convert Multiple Columns to One Large Column (Excel 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073033/convert-multiple-columns-to-one-large-column-excel-2010)

Comment: Here's an even better match from SO: [Stack multiple columns into two colums in pairs of two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613908/stack-multiple-columns-into-two-colums-in-pairs-of-two)

Answer (score 0):

I built a working demo to solve an almost identical problem previously:

https://superuser.com/a/789358/310267

Essentially I unpivot all the Location columns in one Query, all the Qty columns in another Query, then Merge them together in a final Query.