# Excel: sliding range lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry my excel is a bit rusty.

I am trying to do a manual merging with a vlookup on a table that contains several time series. Example

```
      A      B     C      D
1    Date1    V1  Date2    V2
2    Jun-2010 10 Jun-2010 100
3    Jul-2010 15 Aug-2010 120
```

I want to create a new table with

```
      A       B   C
1    Date     V1  V2
2    Jun-2010 10 100
3    Jul-2010 15 NA
4    Aug-2010 NA 100
```

So each column refers to the same date cell but to different ranges in the reference table. I need to slide the range by two columns every time i move one column in the output table.

So after creating a column A in the output table containing all the possible dates (months), cell B2 would have

```
=vlookup($A2, Tab0!A2:B3, 2, 0)
```

and column C2 would have

```
=vlookup($A2, Tab0!C2:D3, 2, 0),
```

and so on.

To do this I am trying to write a vlookup function that takes a sliding range

I tried with R1C1 references, I considered INDEX + MATCH but I always get into some kind of problems.

Comment: Can you clarify which columns are your "fixed" values and which would contain the magic formulas?  IE:  is the new table's columns B and C the columns with the magic formula?  You may need to add for date `Jun-2010` column `B` should contain `xxx` and column `C` should contain `yyyy'

Comment: Mark, i edited the question. i hope it's clearer now. i just need to slide the reference range by two cols when i move one col in the output table. thanks,

Comment: This is very similar to [How to convert one row of data into multiple rows in Excel](http://superuser.com/q/455394/150988), [How do I split one row into multiple rows with Excel?](http://superuser.com/q/633124/150988), and [Transform multiple columns in Excel table into multiple rows](http://superuser.com/q/1022794/150988) — look at those and see whether you can adapt their answers.

Comment: Use absolute reference for the array where the initial Data is located change your formulas like the following: **=vlookup($A2, Tab0!$A$2:$B$3, 2, 0)** and **=vlookup($A2, Tab0!$C$2:$D$3, 2, 0)**

Comment: Change to r1c1 and pass `row` and `column` to `indirect` since it looks like it changes based on formula location

Comment: @Raystafarian I am working in R1C1 mode. It is kind of complicated to set up the indices. I am not sure what you mean by `indirect` (thanks for the edit :-)

Comment: To define a cell, I think you should be able to use `indirect("R[" & row() & "]C[" & column() & "]"), then just define the other edge with adding to the row() and column() formulas

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes! that's what I needed: `indirect`. many thanks.